# Python using lambda to apply pd.DataFrame instead for nested loop is it possible?

Tags: python, performance, nested, pandas

I'm trying to avoid nested loop in python here by using lambda apply to create a new column 
using this argument below :

```
from pandas import *
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame((np.random.rand(100, 4)*100), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda A,B: A+B)
```

TypeError: ('() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)', u'occurred at index A')

Obviously this doesn't work any recommendation ?

Comment: Your apply doesn't work as by default it works column wise, plus you misunderstand what the lambda parameters actually represent so your lambda func does not map to the columns as you expected. If you wanted it to work row wise you need to do something like this `df['c'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.A + row.B, axis=1)` but @miku's answer will achieve what you want and is simpler

Comment: @EdChum, `df.apply(lambda s: s.A + s.C , axis=1)` yields an `AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'A'", u'occurred at index 0')` in pandas 0.12; however, `df.apply(lambda s: s['A'] + s['C'] , axis=1)` works.

Comment: @miku wasn't aware of that, looks like a bug that is now fixed in 0.12, personally I always use `[]` as it reads better to me. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you want to add column `A` and column `B` and store the result in `C`? Then you can have it simpler:

```
df.C = df.A + df.B
```

---

As @EdChum points out in the comment, the argument to the function in `apply` is a series, by default on axis `0` which are rows (axis `1` means columns):

```
>>> df.apply(lambda s: s)[:3]
           A          B          C          D
0  57.890858  72.344298  16.348960  84.109071
1  85.534617  53.067682  95.212719  36.677814
2  23.202907   3.788458  66.717430   1.466331
```

Here, we add the first and the second row:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda s: s[0] + s[1])
A    143.425475
B    125.411981
C    111.561680
D    120.786886
dtype: float64
```

To work on columns, use `axis=1` keyword parameter:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda s: s[0] + s[1], axis=1)
0     130.235156
1     138.602299
2      26.991364
3     143.229523
...
98    152.640811
99     90.266934
```

Which yield the same result as referring to the columns by name:

```
>>> (df.apply(lambda s: s[0] + s[1], axis=1) == 
     df.apply(lambda s: s['A'] + s['B'], axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
...
98    True
99    True
```

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks :)